# Could I create a custom widget in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dojo

I have knowledge of dojo development, but I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap.

In dojo we can write a widget files later we can used in any ware of our projects.

Is it possible to create our own custom widgets in Bootstrap.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean with bootstrap?

Comment: i dont know much about bootstrap. In dojo, if i create a log in widget,i can used any where in my project. same as can i create a widget file in bootstrap?

Comment: I'm asking you what you mean with "bootstrap". The word "bootstrap" has many different meanings, so please clarify.

Comment: I am asking about this http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Ok, you should use the [tag:twitter-bootstrap] tag in stead of [tag:bootstrap]. Seems that @JasonAller already did that for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Dojo has a widget framework that contains features like:

- Inheritance using `dojo/_base/declare` (and the use of mixins)
- Widget lifecycle (thanks to `dijit/_WidgetBase`)
- Templating (thanks to `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` and `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`)
- Framework that allows creating widgets either programmatically or declarative

On the other hand, Twitter Bootstrap is a UI toolkit, containing stylesheets and components that are styled in a similar way. There is (as far as I know) no real widget framework behind it, so things like inheritance, widget lifecycle, ... has to be done by yourself.

So yes, you can create Twitter Bootstrap widgets, but the code for developing your own widget will be a lot more low level, probably using jQuery to realize your widget (or you should find a jQuery based widget framework).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to create your own seperate function for a particular thing. Well actually yes, you can. A bootstrap is actually a framework of CSS JavaScript etc.

If you're talking about Twitter Bootstrap (because that's popular among developers right now), then you should read the documentation of them.

http://getbootstrap.com/

They've got a really nice tutorial for you, to create buttons, form (login form, you're talking about) and other text elements. Read the documentation for the tutorial please.